# How to make a readonly <s:textarea /> fit to its content

Tags: javascript, html, struts2, textarea, struts-tags

I have a textarea in my form :

```xml
<s:textarea key = "appInfo.collection" 
       required = "true" 
       readonly = "true"
       cssClass = "form-control" 
           rows = "8"/>
```

and few more textarea fields. I want to make these textareas fit their content in readonly mode.

Since I have specified `rows=8` it sometimes shows a blank area if content fills only 2 rows, or shows a scrollbar if content is more than 8 rows.

How can I give these textareas the right size based on their content, with no scrollbars ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22715934/1654265

Comment: Sorry but the example didn't work for me. My text areas are in read mode and I do not have keyup function available for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22715934/1654265) linked in my comment.

Regarding your comment

> My text areas are in read mode and I do not have keyup function available for them

You don't need any `keyup` handler: since it is readonly, do it once, after the page has loaded:

```xml
<s:textarea id = "myTextarea"
           key = "appInfo.collection" 
      required = "true" 
      readonly = "true"
      cssClass = "form-control" 
          rows = "8"/>
```

```js
function autoheight(a) {
    if (!$(a).prop('scrollTop')) {
        do {
            var b = $(a).prop('scrollHeight');
            var h = $(a).height();
            $(a).height(h - 5);
        }
        while (b && (b != $(a).prop('scrollHeight')));
    };
    $(a).height($(a).prop('scrollHeight') + 20);
}

$(function(){ 
    // call the function in document.ready 
    autoheight($("#myTextarea"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks , I had done it in same way only thing I forgot is calling it on document.ready() function. I was calling it in <script> tag. It works up to some extent that there are not scroll bars for large text in the fields now. But for small text which is like 1-2 lines it does not re-size to no of lines. Is it because I have not mentioned max height? What should max height be in such case? 50 px? can I use Style for <s:textarea> ?  Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure about your other questions, but I remember I've seen on SO scripts like this with maxHeight handling (for adding scrollbars on big sized textareas), while for the min height it is probably related to some default value, and I'd try changing the *rows* attribute too

Comment: I did change rows attribute already. It works great. Think just need to change the value 20 to something smaller to add little less space at the bottom. Thanks again works for me.