# Textarea's style won't work with Mobile jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, textarea, effects

Following my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930300/force-resizement-when-reading-text-from-file), I have some CSS, but because the textarea lies inside the div that plays the role of a page, it won't work have any effect. Can I somehow do that? The only think that matters to be is to get the border nice and to get the textarea relatively small (now it will take all the width of the screen), like in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1c41ejb/).

```
textarea {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 6px solid #556677;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, when working with jQuery Mobile, !important is your best friend. Without it you can't override aggressive jQuery Mobile CSS.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3qaet2d2/

```
textarea{  
  display:block !important;
  box-sizing: padding-box !important;
  overflow:hidden !important;

  padding:10px !important;
  width:250px !important;
  font-size:14px !important;
  margin:50px auto !important;
  border-radius:8px !important;
  border:6px solid #556677 !important;
}
```

Comment: What is important? That sounds a general question, but I am asking for that thing (how do we call that? an attribute?).

Comment: !important keyword is important. The !important rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied. A rule that has the !important property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document.